# Question feeds seem to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Sepia Lazers, Lazers, and Athena have all seemed to stop posting new questions in the chat room. Is this due to the change to Fastly, or do they just need to be reconfigured again or something? If so could they be fixed when someone gets a chance?

Comment: Athena? Is that from elsewhere?

Comment: @AshleyNunn the Overwatch chat room. Stix set it up I think

Comment: Oh, shiny. I don't go in there so I hadn't seen it.

Comment: I have noticed that other feeds posts in other rooms have stopped working too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheduler was not running properly for chat.se - we gave it a kick, so it should be fine now.